# How do I collapse HTML5 tags in Textmate. (e.g. <section> or <aside>)

Tags: html, textmate

I am  having a hard time figuring out how to collapse HTML5 tags in Textmate.  I've tried installing various HTML5 bundles but none have done the trick.

Collapsing `<div>s` and other HTML4 tags work great, but I would like to be able to collapse all markup that have an opening and closing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always "fold a selection" by highlighting the section you want to fold and hitting <kbd>F1</kbd> (or choosing *Fold Selection* in the right-click menu). The section will stay foldable until deleted.

Not exactly as comfortable as having tag-autofolds, but a good enough workaround to hide the biggest HTML blocks.

Comment: This is a great workaround and I will use this until I can get a definite answer on the tag-autofolds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the built-in HTML bundle doesn't recognize HTML5's `<section>` (etc.) tags. You'll need an HTML5 bundle for that. A google search revealed a few good options with support for the code-folding you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add or remove programs for windows OS,

Open Start Menu + Control Panel + Add or remove program + Select an Application (Google Chrome ) + Click to Change/Uninstall + Follow that Instruction + Restart Your system + Restart not required

Answer (score 0):

Here are some TextMate bundles for HTML5:

- https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5
- https://github.com/bingeboy/TextMate-HTML5-Bundle
- https://github.com/johnmuhl/html5.tmbundle